# confusion with strtotime() 2nd param

Tags: php, datetime

[From PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

> strtotime — Parse about any English textual datetime description into
>   a Unix timestamp Description int strtotime ( string $time [, int $now
>   = time() ] )
>
> The function expects to be given a string containing an English date
>   format and will try to parse that format into a Unix timestamp (the
>   number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC), **relative to the
>   timestamp given in now, or the current time if now is not supplied**.
>
> **Each parameter of this function uses the default time zone unless a
>   time zone is specified in that parameter. Be careful not to use
>   different time zones in each parameter unless that is intended.** See
>   date_default_timezone_get() on the various ways to define the default
>   time zone. Parameters

I don't know whether my q is silly or not, if it is excuse me in advance, but:

I can't get the purpose of the 2nd param, how a UNIX TIMESTAMP (number of Secs past relative to UNIX EPOCH) be relative to another time?

Also I can't understand how a UNIX TIMESTAMP (2nd param) can have time zone?

Comment: You can do for example: `echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+2 hours', strtotime('today')))` The second argument is for temporary setting current time for this function so you can use relative time from other time than current.

Comment: @piotrekkr Aha, now I understand

Answer (score 1):

> I can't understand how a UNIX TIMESTAMP (2nd param) can have time zone?

It doesn't - but the string might be non-UTC while not having an explicit timezone / timezone offset.